# Nvidia problem after inappropriate shut down

Tags: nvidia

After by battery died on my laptop I started my computer after plugging it to the ac adapter, for no reason that I know I cant use the visual effects any more as if my graphic card is not installed (my graphic card is GeForce 300m and nvidia x-settings is working)

I tried generating a new xorg.conf file but nothing happened I marked all the installed nvidia driver in synaptic for re installation and didn't really help

I googled the problem appears to be popular but couldn't find a solid solution

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried to re-install drivers (which I assume proprietary ones, as you talked about nvidia-settings)?
Are you getting the right resolution or low-res mode?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `by` to `my`, `cant` to `can't`, and generally improve the grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks luri for the help but I figured it out

What I did is this:

Downloaded the nvidia driver from their website

reboot -> recovery mode -> root command line level -> uninstall all nvidia drivers -> get down to level 3 "telinit 3" -> stop gdm "service gdm stop" -> delete xorg.conf file -> install nvidia that I downloaded

Everything is now perfect